# File Input reads only last few lines from the input file

Tags: java, file, bufferedreader

It's a simple code to read all the content from a .txt file. Not exactly sure what is the issue. I tried with a different test file and it read just line2 and line4 followed by `null`. It shouldn't even read `null` as per the while loop condition.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class FileInput {

    public ArrayList<String> readFile() {
        ArrayList<String> content = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            File file = new File("input.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file)); 

            String line = null;

            while (br.readLine() != null) {
                line = br.readLine();
                content.add(line);
                System.out.println(line);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("File could not be found. " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        return content;
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {

        FileInput fi = new FileInput();
        fi.readFile();

    }   

}
```

**input.txt**

> Dangal / Aamir Khan / Fatima Sana
>   Sanju / Ranbir Kapoor / Dia Mirza
>   PK / Aamir Khan / Anushka Sharma
>   Munna Bhai MBBS / Sanjay Dutt / Arshad Warsi
>   Zindagi Na Milegi Dobara / Farhan Akhtar / Katrina Kaif

**output:**

> Sanju / Ranbir Kapoor / Dia Mirza
>   Munna Bhai MBBS / Sanjay Dutt / Arshad Warsi
>   null

Am I doing anything incorrectly or did I make a small mistake somewhere?

Comment: You are consuming a line each time in the while loop header without using it `while(br.readLine()!=null)`. Change it to `while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {` and skip the `readLine()` call inside the loop

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are calling `br.readLine()` twice which is causing you to skip a few lines while reading the file within the `while-loop`.

Change your while to as follows :-

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
   content.add(line);
   System.out.println(line);
}
```

Comment: A silly overlook from my side. Changed that the second I saw your response. Appreciate it. Thanks.